# Is there a circle symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a circle symbol for the [composition of two functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)? Or do I have to resort to using other ways to represent that?

Comment: just as a tip, Wikipedia uses LaTeX style markup for their functions. When your press the edit button you can see `:<math>(f\circ f)(x) = f(f(x)) = f^2(x)</math>` ;)

Comment: Just for reference, there is also a filled circle in math mode: `$\bullet$`.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHerenz! The filled circle was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

It's `\circ`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( f \circ f \)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 84):

Probably this is a good chance to recall the [Detexify website](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), where you can simply draw the symbol you want, and obtain the needed code.

I'm a bad illustrator, but for me, after drawing the circle, `\circ` was the first hit.

Comment: I'd like to add that I tried to find this symbol with detexify but I failed as I found many other similar looking symbols but not `\circ`. I actually needed to google "latex combine function symbol", to find this question.

Comment: Would be great if detexify could use context, so you could draw `f o g`.