# Usage of \circle command in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm writing a document in LaTeX, but I can't figure out how I could write the circle symbol in order to indicate the composition of two linear maps, as LaTeX prints "error" when I compile the file. It's weird, as I have seen this in a math book, and I would like to write it in the same format in my file. Here you have what I've done so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\matriu}[3]{M(#1,B_#2,B_#3)}
\newcommand{\vect}[2]{(#1_1,\dots ,#1_#2)}
\begin{document}
Siguin $B_1=\vect{u}{n}$ una base de $E_1$, $B_2=\vect{v}{m}$ una base de $E_2$ i                                            
$B_3=\vect{w}{s}$ una base de $E_3$. Llavors 
\begin{equation*} \matriu{f\circle g}{1}{2}=\matriu{g}{2}{3} \phantom{.} \matriu{f,1,2}     
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your attention and sorry for any inconvenience I may cause (I'm a newbie on LaTeX).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The command is `\circ`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This question is very similar to [Is there a circle symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8301/is-there-a-circle-symbol/8302#8302). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: There are two problems: First, use `\circ` instead of `\circle`. Second, replace `\matriu{f,1,2}` with `\matriu{f}{1}{2}`.

Comment: Yes, I see it's a duplicate, so you can close this question. Thanks for telling me! And yes, it works for \circ! By the way, thanks for spotting the \matriu mistake Mico, but it was just a mistake I had done while typing fast :) I hope you have a great day all of you!