# Circle symbol compatible with \square and \triangle

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need a circle symbol that is somehow compatible (from a layout point of view) with `\square` and `\triangle`. As you can see in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\circ AB$, $\bigcirc AB$, $\square ABCD$,  $\triangle ABC$, 
\end{document}
```

the square and the triangle are a perfect match, but none of the circle symbols match. Is there a way to get a circle aligned with bottom line of the text and with a comparable height as the other two symbols? **In maths mode.**

[image]

I've seen this question, but is not the right one for my situation:
[Is there a circle symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8301/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can scale `\bigcirc` down:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\iscircle}{\mathord{\mathpalette\is@circle\relax}}
\newcommand\is@circle[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\bigcirc$}}%
  \sbox\tw@{$#1\square$}%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\tw@}{\usebox{\z@}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\iscircle AB$, $\square ABCD$,  $\triangle ABC$,

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was entering my answer but one time Davide beat with a slingshot, Goliath :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some other possibilities: use `ocircle` from `wasysym`, raised slightly (the regular symbol is rendered below the baseline), or use TikZ and print a tight circle around a lower case letter (but don't print the letter).

The commands can be defined in a simple way that scales with the font but not with sub- and superscript, or as a more math-aware version using `\mathchoice`. The solution in the other answer is also included, note that the circle is a little flat in the subscript of the normal size example, but round in the `\Huge` version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\iscircle}{\mathord{\mathpalette\is@circle\relax}}
\newcommand\is@circle[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\bigcirc$}}%
  \sbox\tw@{$#1\square$}%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\tw@}{\usebox{\z@}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\wacircsimple}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{$\ocircle$}}
\newcommand{\tkzcircsimple}{\tikz{\node[circle,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw]{$\phantom{o}$}}}
\newcommand{\wacircscale}{\mathchoice%
{\raisebox{0.2ex}{$\displaystyle\ocircle$}}%
{\raisebox{0.2ex}{$\textstyle\ocircle$}}%
{\raisebox{0.2ex}{$\scriptstyle\ocircle$}}%
{\raisebox{0.2ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\ocircle$}}%
}
\newcommand{\tkzcircscale}{\mathchoice%
{\tikz{\node[circle,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw]{$\displaystyle \phantom{o}$}}}%
{\tikz{\node[circle,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw]{$\textstyle \phantom{o}$}}}%
{\tikz{\node[circle,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw]{$\scriptstyle \phantom{o}$}}}%
{\tikz{\node[circle,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw]{$\scriptscriptstyle \phantom{o}$}}}%
}

\begin{document}
$\square\iscircle BA_{\iscircle AB_{\iscircle AB}}$

$\square\wacircsimple BA_{\wacircsimple AB_{\wacircsimple AB}}$

$\square\wacircscale BA_{\wacircscale AB_{\wacircscale AB}}$

$\square\tkzcircsimple BA_{\tkzcircsimple AB_{\tkzcircsimple AB}}$

$\square\tkzcircscale BA_{\tkzcircscale AB_{\tkzcircscale AB}}$

\Huge
$\square\iscircle BA_{\iscircle AB_{\iscircle AB}}$

$\square\wacircsimple BA_{\wacircsimple AB_{\wacircsimple AB}}$

$\square\wacircscale BA_{\wacircscale AB_{\wacircscale AB}}$

$\square\tkzcircsimple BA_{\tkzcircsimple AB_{\tkzcircsimple AB}}$

$\square\tkzcircscale BA_{\tkzcircscale AB_{\tkzcircscale AB}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion the TikZ version looks better in the normal font (considering line width) but in the `\Huge` version the `wasysym` symbol looks better.

Comment: Very nice solution (tikz). Upvoted. And your solution has the advantage that you could change the line thickness of the circle in such a way that it is equal to the one of the square; this being the only perceivable drawback of the solution of egreg. One could adapt the line width for every style, couldn't?